# Magento 1.11 Fatal Error: Class 'Namespace_Module_Helper_Data' not found in Mage.php

Tags: magento

I have created a module, it is throwing fatal error on admin

```
Fatal Error: Class 'Namespace_Module_Helper_Data' not found in Mage.php
```

However, this helper class exists in module. This module works fine with Magento 1.10.

I am not able to figure out the problem. Any guesses??

Comment: you said it is working in other version, but still crosscheck that declaration of helper is there in config.xml

Comment: yes, declaration of helper is there in config.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check if compilation is enabled from admin > system > Tools > compilation. If you have added extension without disabling the compilation it may cause this problem. 
Clear cache & rerun the compilation process again. Hope this may solve your problem.